# How to resize a Folder View widget on the desktop?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 16.04, plasma-5

It's surely my fault, but I am not able to resize the folder view widgets I've put on the desktop.

In the previous release (14.04, KDE 4) the folder view widgets all had auto-appearing hanldes for setup, rotation and resize, among other features.

Now I have no clue how to do it.
Any idea?

Comment: I just had the exact same problem with 16.04, and no problems with 14.04 resizing.  I've been trying all day.  No one will ever discover this feature!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found!

**You need to click and hold into a widget in order to have the handles appearing.**

It's quite different from KDE4 where the handles appeared by hovering the pointer on one side of the the widget!

Comment: This behavior can be changed back in Desktop Settings (right click on desktop) -> Tweaks -> Widget Handling. Source:  [bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359220).

Comment: Cool! Good to know!

Comment: Wow that is atrocious! Since when do you long click with a mouse? You know your UI sucks when people have to Google how to do something basic like move/resize.

Comment: @Mike totally. I'm switching to XFCE right now. Just had enough of Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Also, right-clicking the widget brings option to access its settings and option to remove it.

[image]

That is - if widgets are **not** locked. If they are locked, only settings are accessible.

Comment: But you cannot *resize* the widget, only change the other settings.